# solving and optimization polynomial spline

Tags: optimization, wolfram-mathematica, spline

First I would  thank the Mathematica community.

i have a system like this:

```
s(x)=
  -2035.5111 + 561.33713 x -51.262777 x^2 + 1.5534175 x^3    x in [10, 11]
  -2035.5111 + 561.33713 x - 51.262777 x^2 + 1.5534175 x^3   x in [11, 12] 
   7158.3214 - 1737.121 x + 140.2754 x^2 - 3.7670874 x^3     x in [12, 13]
  -11037.276 +  2461.863 x - 182.72337 x^2 + 4.5149323 x^3   x in [13, 14]
   9375.4483 - 1912.2922 x + 129.71629 x^2 - 2.9241071 x^3   x in [14, 15]
  -38343.961 + 7035.097 x - 429.49554 x^2 + 8.7261392 x^3    x in [15, 16]
   45546.119 - 7769.0348 x + 441.33575 x^2 - 8.348984 x^3    x in [16, 17]
  -24547.41 + 3913.2201 x - 207.67842 x^2 + 3.6697968 x^3    x in [17, 18]
  -24547.41 + 3913.2201 x - 207.67842 x^2 + 3.6697968 x^3    x in [18, 19]
```

How can I solve the system, `m <= s(x) <= M`, where `m` and `M` are not null and real.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
With[{m=4.5,M=5},
Map[Reduce[#,x]&,
{m<=-2035.5111 + 561.33713 x -51.262777 x^2 + 1.5534175 x^3<=M && 10<=x<=11,
 m<=-2035.5111 + 561.33713 x - 51.262777 x^2 + 1.5534175 x^3<=M && 11<=x<=12,
 m<=7158.3214 - 1737.121 x + 140.2754 x^2 - 3.7670874 x^3<=M && 12<=x<=13,
 m<=-11037.276 +  2461.863 x - 182.72337 x^2 + 4.5149323 x^3<=M && 13<=x<=14,
 m<=9375.4483 - 1912.2922 x + 129.71629 x^2 - 2.9241071 x^3<=M && 14<=x<=15,
 m<=-38343.961 + 7035.097 x - 429.49554 x^2 + 8.7261392 x^3<=M && 15<=x<=16,
 m<=45546.119 - 7769.0348 x + 441.33575 x^2 - 8.348984 x^3<=M && 16<=x<=17,
 m<=-24547.41 + 3913.2201 x - 207.67842 x^2 + 3.6697968 x^3<=M && 17<=x<=18,
 m<=-24547.41 + 3913.2201 x - 207.67842 x^2 + 3.6697968 x^3<=M && 18<=x<=19}
]]
```

which will give you this

```
{x == 10. || 10.554622537850287<=x<=10.799264882501637,
 False,
 12.437932301023451<=x<=12.565380177021947,
 13.489415750912576<=x<=13.655683693607168,
 14.254978447526584<=x<=14.383489034636659,
 15.243856830113526<=x<=15.265292288384687,
 16.544981470615802<=x<=16.568935210200074,
 17.897288052000384<=x<=18.,
 18.<=x<=18.00034993487379 || 18.49992074750174<=x<=18.64596353629056}
```

where each line of that corresponds to the zero or more solutions with the corresponding equation in your s(x).

You can compare that solution with this graph

```
Show[
Plot[Piecewise[{
{-2035.5111 + 561.33713 x -51.262777 x^2 + 1.5534175 x^3,10<=x<=11},
{ -2035.5111 + 561.33713 x - 51.262777 x^2 + 1.5534175 x^3,11<=x<=12},
{ 7158.3214 - 1737.121 x + 140.2754 x^2 - 3.7670874 x^3,12<=x<=13},
{ -11037.276 +  2461.863 x - 182.72337 x^2 + 4.5149323 x^3,13<=x<=14},
{ 9375.4483 - 1912.2922 x + 129.71629 x^2 - 2.9241071 x^3,14<=x<=15},
{ -38343.961 + 7035.097 x - 429.49554 x^2 + 8.7261392 x^3,15<=x<=16},
{ 45546.119 - 7769.0348 x + 441.33575 x^2 - 8.348984 x^3,16<=x<=17},
{ -24547.41 + 3913.2201 x - 207.67842 x^2 + 3.6697968 x^3,17<=x<=18},
{ -24547.41 + 3913.2201 x - 207.67842 x^2 + 3.6697968 x^3,18<=x<=19}}],{x,10,19}],
Plot[{4.5,5},{x,10,19}]
]
```

and look at the segments between y==4.5 and y==5 and it seems to match.

Depending on what you want to do with this, it would be possible to turn all this into a single disjunction by putting `Or@@` in front of the `With` and to combine alternatives like

```
17.897288052000384 <= x <= 18. || 18. <= x <= 18.00034993487379
```

into

```
17.897288052000384 <= x <= 18.00034993487379
```

using pattern matching replacement.

This does display messages about Reduce needing to turn your decimal numbers into rationals to be able to use appropriate algorithms, but if those are the only messages then it should be safe to accept those. All messages should be carefully watched.

Check this very carefully with your actual m and M to make absolutely certain that this is correct.

Comment: How do you find m=4.5 and M=5

Comment: My answer used `Reduce` to find the intervals where each of your expressions were between `m` and `M`. I picked example values for `m` and `M` to show it working. This method should work for any `m` and `M` that you choose.

Comment: Looking at the original question and the tag “optimization”, I have the strong feeling that the min and max value of the spline are searched. For example, this could be done with optim function in Scilab.